# setTimeout when preloading images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following codes to preload album images and show a loading bar.

```
var album1 = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg'];
var album2 = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg'];
var total_images = album1.length + album2.length;
var load_count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  function preloadImages(list, path) {
        var img;
        if (!preloadImages.cache) {
            preloadImages.cache = [];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            $(img).bind('load', function() {
                load_count++;
                $('#loading_bar #progress').css('width', Math.round(load_count * 100 / total_images) + '%');
                if(load_count >= total_images) {
                    init_sequence();
                }
            });
            img.src = path + list[i];
            preloadImages.cache.push(img);
        }
    }

  preloadImages(album1, 'http://www.example.com/images/path1/');
  preloadImages(album2, 'http://www.example.com/images/path2/');
}
```

The above preloading codes work fine in normal network condition. However when network is unstable, making one of the images unable to load, the function `init_sequence()` cannot be triggered.

My question is, how can I set a timeout (probably using `setTimeout()` on above function) in preloading images (e.g. if the preload cannot finish in 30 seconds, load the `init_sequence()` anyways)?

---

**Additional Information:**

In case somebody needs to know the HTML structure, here it is (allow me to show only the `<body>` part; I have included jQuery for sure):

```
<body>
  <div id="loading_bar">
    <div id="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
#loading_bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
#loading_bar #progress {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: #A68029;
}
```

Comment: This is not so hard. I mean you have to create a catalog of your file names and check after 30 seconds, that every file is loaded in the catalog. Whenever a file is registered, but not loaded, you can drop it, and display only the others. What is your problem?

Comment: in JS, the image can still be loaded without preloading, but the user experience is no good when user enters a page with lots of images loading in progress.

Comment: Okay, then just add a plus variable called `initialized` and check whether it is true or false after 30 secs. You should set it true by calling the init. If it is not true after 30 secs, then call the init.

Comment: this should work too.

Comment: I don't understand, you have 14k of reputation and you have to ask this question? :D

Comment: reputation is just a number; i post every question that i think people may be interested in, and more importantly, find the *best solution*. One problem can be solved in many ways, but not all solutions are efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a timeout variable like below.

```
var album1 = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg'];
var album2 = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg'];
var total_images = album1.length + album2.length;
var load_count = 0;



$(document).ready(function() {
    // A flag to check if loading timeout had been reached
    var loadTimeout = false;

    function preloadImages(list, path) {

        var img;
        if (!preloadImages.cache) {
            preloadImages.cache = [];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            img = new Image();
            $(img).bind('load', function() {
                load_count++;
                $('#loading_bar #progress').css('width', Math.round(load_count * 100 / total_images) + '%');
                if(load_count >= total_images) {
                    // If we get this far, then clear the timeout variable
                    clearTimeout(timeout);

                    // If the image is loaded after timeout, then do nothing because init_sequence have been called.
                    if (loadTimeout == false) {
                        init_sequence();
                    }
                }
            });
            img.src = path + list[i];
            preloadImages.cache.push(img);
        }
    }
    // Set timeout for 30 seconds
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        loadTimeout = true;
        init_sequence();
    }, 30000); 
    preloadImages(album1, 'http://www.example.com/images/path1/');
    preloadImages(album2, 'http://www.example.com/images/path2/');
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `init_sequence` might be called more than once here if all the images are loading successfully after the 30 seconds timeout. You can either remove the handlers or ignore subsequent `init_sequence` calls however.

Comment: @plalx I did use `clearTimeout(timeout);` do you notice that? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, I aware of this when I try to test the updated JavaScript codes. the `setTimeout()` is called multiple times, as `preloadImages()` calls twice in my question.

Comment: @TrungDQ Yes you cleared the timeout, but you haven't prevented the call of `init_sequence` once every images will be successfully loaded after it.

Comment: @plalx Yes, thanks, that my mistake. I have just updated my answer.

Comment: `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` are still called twice. The first call to `setTimeout()` will be override by 2nd time. Is that still okay?

Comment: If you want to do the `init_sequence()` for each album after loading then it is necessary to `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` for each album.

Comment: Sorry for misleading: `init_sequence()` only requires to be called once, after all images have been preloaded / timed out. Thanks.

Comment: In that case I have moved some variables to a wider scope. Check my updated asnswer,

Comment: @ShivanRaptor `init_sequence` will still be called multiple times since `preloadImages` is called more than once. You should change your method signature to handle multiple albums at a time.

Comment: No, it won't, as only when all images area loaded `if(load_count >= total_images)`, the function will be called.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Oh yeah sorry, I thought these counters were private to the function itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var initialized = false;
function init_sequence(){
    if (initialized)
        return;
    initialized = true;
    //...
}

setTimeout(init_sequence, 30000);
```

Well in my case it would be something like this (or I'd use promises instead of observers), I like to be oo... But I don't think this is acceptable for you ;-)

```
var Observer = function (){
    this.listeners = {};
};
Observer.prototype = {
    constructor: Observer,
    register: function (type){
        this.listeners[type] = [];
    },
    on: function (type, callback){
        this.listeners[type].push(callback);
    },
    off: function (type){
        this.listeners[type].length = 0;
    },
    trigger: function (type){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        var listeners = this.listeners[type];
        for (var i=0, l=listeners.length; i<l; ++i){
            var listener = listeners[i];
        }
    }
};

var Map = function (){
    this.data = {};
};
Map.prototype = {
    constructor: Map,
    length: 0,
    set: function (key, value){
        if (!this.has(key))
            ++this.length;
        this.data[key] = value;
    },
    has: function (key){
        return this.data.hasOwnProperty(key);
    },
    get: function (key){
        if (this.has(key))
            return this.data[key];
    },
    remove: function (key){
        if (this.has(key))
            --this.length;
        delete(this.data[key]);
    },
    each: function (callback){
        for (var key in this.data)
            if (this.has(key))
                callback(this.get(key), key);
    }
};

var ImagePreloader = function (){
    this.loaded = new Map();
    this.loading = new Map();
    this.observer = new Observer();
    this.observer.register("progress");
    this.observer.register("complete");
};
ImagePreloader.prototype = {
    constructor: ImagePreloader,
    on: function (type, callback){
        this.observer.on(type, callback);
    },
    off: function (type){
        this.observer.off(type);
    },
    trigger: function (type){
        this.observer.trigger.apply(this.observer, arguments);
    },
    percent: function (){
        var totalCount = this.loading.length + this.loaded.length;
        if (!totalCount)
            return 0;
        return Math.round(100 * this.loading.length / totalCount);
    },
    load: function (url){
        if (this.loading.has(url) || this.loaded.has(url))
            return;
        var image = new Image();
        this.loading.set(url, image);
        $(image).bind("load", function() {
            this.success(url);
        }.bind(this));
        image.src = url;
        this.progress();
    },
    success: function (url){
        var image = this.loading.get(url);
        this.loading.remove(url);
        this.loaded.set(url, image);
        this.progress();
    },
    progress: function (){
        var percent = this.percent();
        this.observer.trigger("progress", percent);
        if (percent == 100)
            this.observer.trigger("complete");
    }
}

var ProgressBar = function (){
};
ProgressBar.prototype = {
    constructor: ProgressBar,
    $el: null,
    percent: 0,
    setElement: function (el){
        this.$el = $(el);
    },
    setProgress: function (percent){
        this.percent = percent;
    },
    render: function (){
        if (!this.$el)
            return;
        this.$el.css("width", this.percent + "%");
    }
};

var Album = function (baseUrl, pathes){
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl || "/";
    this.images = new Map();
    if (pathes)
        this.pushAll(pathes);
};
Album.prototype = {
    constructor: Album,
    length: 0,
    pushAll: function (pathes){
        for (var i=0, l=pathes.length; i<l; ++i)
            this.push(images[i]);
    },
    push: function (path){
        var url = baseUrl + path;
        this.images.set(path, url);
        this.length = this.images.length;
    },
    each: function (callback){
        this.images.each(callback);
    }
};

var Main = {
    run: function (){
        var albums = this.createAlbums();
        this.preloadAlbums(albums, this.renderAlbums.bind(this));
    },
    createAlbums: function (){
        var albums = new Map();
        albums.set("album1", new Album(
            'http://www.example.com/images/path1/',
            ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg']
        ));
        albums.set("album2", new Album(
            'http://www.example.com/images/path2/',
            ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg']
        ));
        return albums;
    },
    preloadAlbums: function (albums, complete){
        var timeoutSeconds = 30;
        var progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            progressBar.setElement('#loading_bar #progress');
        });
        var preloader = new ImagePreloader();
        preloader.on("progress", function (percent){
            progressBar.setProgress(percent);
            progressBar.render();
        });
        preloader.on("complete", function (){
            preloader.off("complete");
            complete(albums);
        });
        albums.each(function (album){
            album.each(function (url){
                preloader.load(url);
            });
        });
        setTimeout(function (){
            preloader.trigger("complete");
        }, timeoutSeconds * 1000);
    },
    renderAlbums: function (albums){
        init_sequence();
    }
};

Main.run();
```

Btw. I don't think you have to wait until `ready` to start preloading images...

Comment: clarification: `init_sequence()` is a series of animation. When I finish loading images in `preloadImages()`, I call `init_sequence()` to start animation. I just can't figure out this code can be merged with my current logic.

Comment: You can check the `initialized` before calling `init_sequence`. I just did not want to copy-paste your whole code...